# pass a flash message along with a gsp g:link

Tags: grails, gsp

In a grails3 create view, I'd like to have the **Cancel button** which just points back to the index page. On the index page, I'd like to display a message informing about the cancellation.

```
<g:link controller="${controllerName}" action="index" class="btn btn-default" params="[flash.message: 'Create cancelled']">
    Cancel
</g:link>
```

The above button is just a non-working mockup, no message is popping up. What would be the best way to achieve a `flash.message` popping up on the next page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just redirect from a cancel action say:

gsp

```
<g:link controller="${controllerName}" action="cancel" class="btn btn-default">
    Cancel
</g:link>
```

Controller

```
def cancel(){
    flash.message = message( code: 'cancel.message.in.messages.properties' )
    redirect(action: 'index')
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm and IMHO is fully following the grails way, thank you very much!